# POST data after HTML form submit is empty, request type is POST though

Tags: php, html

So, I'm trying to POST some data from an HTML form to a PHP script. This is the form I'm using:

```
<form style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px;" action="order2.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Service Type</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="service">
      <?php
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM services ORDER BY name ASC";
          $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
          $statement->execute();
          $statement->store_result();

          $result = get_result($statement);

          while($data = array_shift($result)) {
            echo('<option>'.$data['name'].'</option>');
          }
      ?>
    </select>
    <small id="serviceHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Amount</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="1000">
    <small id="priceHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Link</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="link" placeholder="">
    <small id="linkHelp" class="form-text text-muted"><strong>Warning</strong>! Please keep to the format of the example provided!</small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>e*pvp Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="i0N">
    <small id="linkHelp" class="form-text text-muted"><strong>Warning</strong>! Please make sure your username is correct (copy & paste it), because the payment will fail otherwise!</small>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align: center;"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;">Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

As you can see on the very top, the "method" is set to "post". The form redirects me successfully, and when I take a look at the request through the inspector, it also shows me that a POST request was made. However, there's no data whatsoever passed. If I try to `var_dump($_POST);`, it also only shows `array(0) { }`. What am I missing?

I also permanently get this PHP error in my error_log when submitting the form:

```
[30-Jul-2018 04:14:28 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: service in /home/maxkygbx/public_html/epvpsocial/order2.php on line 6
[30-Jul-2018 04:14:28 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: service in /home/maxkygbx/public_html/epvpsocial/order2.php on line 7
```

Here's the corresponding lines:

```
<?php
  if(is_null($_POST['service']) || $_POST['service'] == ""){
    echo($_POST['service']);
    die();
  }
```

Comment: Try adding the name element to your inputs and selects.


`<input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="1000">`

Comment: Your PHP code is a bit peculiar. You echo a value you know to be null or empty? To avoid notices if the POST value is not set, you could change your if statement to `if(empty($_POST['service']))`, although echoing the value of an array element you know to be empty could still raise notices (and is still probably not what you mean to be doing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input fields does not have any "name" attribute.

Your input has to look like this :

```
<input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="1000">
```

Comment: Yep - I overlooked this. I kept using 'id' but it has to be 'name' for it to show up in the POST / GET.

Answer (score 3):

To send a `POST` or `GET` your input should have `name` attribute
After that you can access it

HTML

```
<input type='text' name='phone'>
```

PHP

```
<?php echo $_POST['phone'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The query string (name/value pairs) is sent in the URL of a GET or POST request:

```
/stacktest/example_form.php?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

the name is an anchor tag which is needed when using a `POST` or `GET` method. Therefore, you need to use a `name` value so that the values are linked and are saved.